# Cracking the Coding Interview, 6th edition, 1.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, rotation

Given an image represented by nxn matrix, where each pixel in image is 4 bytes, write a method to rotate the image by 90 degrees. (In place)

I did the inefficient solution which was copying each row to a temp then performing the swaps, took o(N) space, the actual solution below is better but I dont understand it.

```py
def rotate_matrix(matrix):
    '''rotates a matrix 90 degrees clockwise'''
    n = len(matrix)
    for layer in range(n // 2):
        first, last = layer, n - layer - 1
        for i in range(first, last):
            # save top
            top = matrix[layer][i]

            # left -> top
            matrix[layer][i] = matrix[-i - 1][layer]

            # bottom -> left
            matrix[-i - 1][layer] = matrix[-layer - 1][-i - 1]

            # right -> bottom
            matrix[-layer - 1][-i - 1] = matrix[i][- layer - 1]

            # top -> right
            matrix[i][- layer - 1] = top
    return matrix
```

The code above is the Python solution,

I dont understand the for loops, why is it in range n//2 and from first to n-layer-1.

Also, why does the question mention the 4 bytes it seems like useless information.

Thank you !

Comment: in python `4 bytes` is not important but in other languages you may have to know how big array you have to reserve to copy values.

Comment: it uses `n // 2` because it replaces pixels in squares which have size `(n // 2, n // 2)`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to consider if `n` is odd or even, because the problem must be approached in subtly different ways. In either case, though, the square can be broken down into quadrants.

#### `n` is odd:

The square gets broken down into four rectangular quadrants. In each iteration of the double for-loop, exactly 4 elements are rotated, one from each of the quadrants. The middle element is never accessed because it remains in the middle in a rotation.

```
+-------+---+ 
| x   x | x | 
+---+---+   | 
| x | x | x | 
|   +---+---+ 
| x | x   x | 
+---+-------+
```

#### `n` is even case:

The matrix is broken down into 4 squares quadrants. Again, in each iteration of the double for-loop, exactly 4 elements are rotated, one from each quadrant.
In the even case, every element must be moved (i.e. there is no perfect center element).

```
+-------+-------+
| x   x | x   x |
|       |       |
| x   x | x   x |
+-------+-------+
| x   x | x   x |
|       |       |
| x   x | x   x |
+-------+-------+
```

The `n // 2` and `n - layer - 1` are just floor and ceiling functions in disguise. Floor and ceiling are needed for the `n` is odd case. Those values are used to setup an iteration over one of the quadrants. Then for however many elements exist in *one* of the quadrants, the 4 swaps occur in place (with the help of the `top` temporary value).

Answer (score 4):

Basically we rotate elements by going from the outer border to the inner core of our matrix, swapping items clockwise.

Let´s take the following matrix as an example:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

In the first iteration we are concerned about the outer elements:

```
1  2  3  4
5  x  x  8
9  x  x  12
13 14 15 16
```

There we start (inner loop) to swap all elements clockwise. In our example we replace the 4 (after having it stored in a temp var) with the 1. After that we replace the 1 with the 13 and so on. Finally we replace the 16 with our saved 4. We continue doing that until all elements have been swapped. So after the first iteration of the outer loop our array looks like this:

```
13  9  5 1
14  6  7 2 
15 10 11 3
16 12  8 4
```

After that we move to the next Layer. In our case we now have a look at:

```
x  x  x x
x  6  7 x 
x 10 11 x
x x  x  x
```

We we again swap all elements one by one as shown above. We have floor n/2 iterations because for uneven n the very last iteration leaves us with a single element, which obviously does not need to be rotated.

Which leaves us with:

```
13  9 5 1
14 10 6 2 
15 11 7 3
16 12 8 4
```

The 4 bytes are needed for languages like c where we would have to manage the memory by hand. Their origin is most likely the fact that each pixel consists of 3 colors (red, green and blue) and each color is represented by 8 bits (0-255). Additionally there could be another 8 bits for the opacity. So we are left with 32 bits = 4 bytes.